# Converting Spring task XML configuration to code configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration, scheduled-tasks, task

I'm trying to convert XML configuration for using Spring's tasks framework into purely code configuration. I'm able to reproduce the functionality but whenever I shut down the war on the Tomcat server the task scheduler lives on, it hangs (it doesn't hang with XML configuration). I've debugged to inspect the instances of scheduler and executor but I'm not seeing a difference so I'm not sure what could be causing it to hang.

Here is the XML configuration that works:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">

   <task:executor id="com.work.gwx.pix.executor"
      pool-size="${pix.job.executor.pool.size:1-40}"
      queue-capacity="${pix.job.executor.queue.capacity:0}"
      rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

   <task:scheduler id="com.work.gwx.pix.scheduler" pool-size="${pix.job.scheduler.pool.size:4}"  />

    <task:annotation-driven executor="com.work.gwx.pix.executor" scheduler="com.work.gwx.pix.scheduler" />

    <bean id='queueProcessor' class="com.work.gwx.queueing.QueueProcessor" /> 

 </beans>
```

Here is the code configuration:

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class TaskConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer, SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Value("${pix.job.executor.max.pool.size:1}")
    private int executorMaxPoolSize;

    @Value("${pix.job.executor.queue.capacity:0}")
    private int executorQueueCapacity;

    @Value("${pix.job.scheduler.pool.size:4}")
    private int schedulerPoolSize;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Executor pixTaskScheduler() {
        final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(schedulerPoolSize, new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor());
        // ex.setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
        return ex;
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor pixExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(executorMaxPoolSize);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(executorQueueCapacity);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.setThreadFactory(new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor());
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(final ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(pixTaskScheduler());

    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return pixExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

When I use `setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false)` in code configuration it does shut down but I'm worried that might have adverse effects as that is set to true when done via XML configuration. Also, I should note, the QueueProcessor class is doing the work I want and I don't mind if delayed executions get cancelled -- I just don't want currently executing threads to be abruptly cancelled.

This is the message I get when it hangs:

> SEVERE: The web application [/pix-queue-processor] appears to have
>   started a thread named [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1] but has failed to
>   stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Any ideas on what might be causing the hanging? Or, would using that commented out method let me do what I want (won't kill a running task but will cancel delayed tasks)?

Comment: One of the problems I see is that you are setting a new `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as `ThreadFactory`? Why? You now basically have 2 task executors where one is controlled and the other not really.

Comment: Another things is is why aren't you wiring your `TaskExecutor` to your `TaskScheduler`? That is using, yet another unmanaged `TaskExecutor`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Java based configuration isn't really a representation of the the XML configuration. There are at least 2 things that are different.

1. Your `TaskExecutor` has another `TaskExecutor` wired as a `ThreadFactory` this isn't the case in XML and also starts another `TaskExecutor`.
2. Your `TaskScheduler` uses a new `TaskExecutor` whereas the xml configuration use the one configured.

The have your task finished on shutdown you can set the `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` property on the `TaskExecutor` to `true` then any pending tasks will be completed and no new tasks will be accepted.

Also the call to `initialize` shouldn't be needed as the `afterPropertiesSet` method will be called by Spring which in turn calls `initialize`.

The following 2 bean definitions are more in line with the XML configuration (and you now have a single `TaskExecutor` instead of 3 and it will first finish tasks before shutdown.

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public Executor pixTaskScheduler() {
    final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(schedulerPoolSize, pixExecutor());
    // ex.setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
    return ex;
}

@Bean
public Executor pixExecutor() {
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(executorMaxPoolSize);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(executorQueueCapacity);
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    return executor;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded to this yet as I was out of town. Looks promising and should be able to test it out soon. It makes sense what you're saying.

Comment: This does seem to work but one more question: In the XML, I'm able to give a name/id to both the executor and scheduler. How could I do that via code? The ThreadPoolTaskExecutor seems to have a method but not the Scheduled one. This would really help identify which threads are coming from this when debugging.

Comment: No it won't because there is only a single thread pool. For the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` you can use the `threadNamePrefix` to add a prefix. But the scheduler is just a scheduler which uses the single `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` to launch tasks. If you don't want that you need to add another task executor, but that isn't what you have (or had) in your xml configuration.